# What is the Authority field when "solana program show" is ran?

Tags: account, solana-cli

Solana account is represented by the AccountInfo struct, which can be seen [here](https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/account_info/struct.AccountInfo.html) and whose structure is basically this:

```
pub struct AccountInfo<'a> {
    pub key: &'a Pubkey,
    pub is_signer: bool,
    pub is_writable: bool,
    pub lamports: Rc<RefCell<&'a mut u64>>,
    pub data: Rc<RefCell<&'a mut [u8]>>,
    pub owner: &'a Pubkey,
    pub executable: bool,
    pub rent_epoch: Epoch,
}
```

Now I am reading this page of the documentation about showing the program account from the command line. See [here](https://docs.solana.com/cli/deploy-a-program#showing-a-program-account)

The following command was ran:

```
solana program show <ACCOUNT_ADDRESS>
```

and the result shown as:

```
Program Id: 3KS2k14CmtnuVv2fvYcvdrNgC94Y11WETBpMUGgXyWZL
Owner: BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111
ProgramData Address: EHsACWBhgmw8iq5dmUZzTA1esRqcTognhKNHUkPi4q4g
Authority: FwoGJNUaJN2zfVEex9BB11Dqb3NJKy3e9oY3KTh9XzCU
Last Deployed In Slot: 63890568
Data Length: 5216 (0x1460) bytes
```

Now I am not sure how to map this to `AccountInfo`. Specifically what is `Authority`? is it the same as `key` in `AccountInfo`?

Also how does `ProgramData Address` from the output corresponds to `data` in `AccountInfo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authority is the address which deployed the program on the blockchain. Only this address has the authority to upgrade the program. You can't map it within the program.

No, key in `AccountInfo` is not the `Authority`. Key is the public key of the account. In your case, it will be `3KS2k14CmtnuVv2fvYcvdrNgC94Y11WETBpMUGgXyWZL` for the program account.